# How to get list of all ApplicationUsers who are in certain Role from database by LINQ expression?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6.1

I want to get:

- list of `ApplicationUsers` who are in role `"NormalUser"` to anybody
- list of all `ApplicationUsers` only to Admins only.

I did this:

```
// GET: ApplicationUsers
public ActionResult Index() {
    // if you are Admin you will get all users
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) 
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
   //if you are somebody else(not Admin) you will see only list of NormalUsers
   //HERE I GET ERROR 
   var list = db.Users.Where(x => UserManager.IsInRole(x.Id, "NormalUser")).ToList(); // here I get error
    return View(list);
}
```

UserManager inside code above is: `UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));`

But unfortunately my LINQ expresiion is incorrect. I get error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsInRole[ApplicationUser,String](Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2[WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationUser,System.String], System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

**Question:** How to correctly get list of users who are in role `"NormalUser"`?

Comment: How are roles stored in the Application User? Is it one role per user, or can one user belong to multiple roles? I'll add an answe, see how it does for you.

Answer (score 4):

The UserManager.IsInRole function isn't supported at the database, but if your application can bear the weight of pulling the whole User table back from the database before applying your filter then you can just add a ToList between your Users table reference and your Where filter, i.e.

```
var list = db.Users.ToList().Where(x => UserManager.IsInRole(x.Id, "NormalUser")).ToList();
```

Comment: this will load all users in memory

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It worked, but I don't know why and I don't know what's going on with efficiency of this solution. In current scenario there will be at most 20 users, but later on I don't know.

Comment: Yes, this will load all users in memory. Don't do it if you're eBay. Have updated with explanation and caveat.

Comment: make some way to filter them from database, this will be a big issue as users increases with time

Answer (score 3):

I reached here for a good quick answer but could not find one. So decided to put on what I got for any other visitor who comes here. To get the List of Users in any particular Role, one can use this code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<ApplicationUser> appUsers=new List<ApplicationUser>();
        await Task.Run( () =>
        {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>( new RoleStore<IdentityRole>( db ) );
            var adminRole=roleManager.FindByName("Admin");
            appUsers = db.Users.Where( x => x.Roles.Any( s => s.RoleId == adminRole.Id ) ).ToList();
        } );
        return View( appUsers );
    }
```

Comment: You can skip the roleManager part if you're willing to just hard-code the role ID (I really don't see why not, having separate IDs and Names for roles seems redundant to me) but otherwise this seems like the right way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It would be useful to know how Roles and Application users relate.

If the user can only belong to one role, it would be fine for you to do something like this:

```
var list = db.Users.ToList().Where(x => x.Role == "NormalUser").ToList();
```

Id the user can be part of multiple roles, it would look something more like this:

```
var list = db.Users.ToList().Where(x => x.Roles.Contains("NormalUser")).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Users can belong to multiple roles. However, your statements won't compile because `x.Role` is not a string type. Needs to be `x.Roles.Any( s => s.RoleId == adminRole.Id )` as in the answer above.